# Firebase background notification crash

Tags: java, android, firebase, nullpointerexception, notifications

i am building a chat app by using firebase in which i am using feature function log to display notification in android.I have created a Reqactivity  if a person sends request to some guy it shows in his guy android then if a guy click on it will retrive it to Reqactivity.The problem is that if the guy android is running the app in foreground and he clicks in it will take him to that Reqactivity if he is running background if he click that notification app gets crashed due to error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aquib.chatapp/com.example.aquib.chatapp.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

this where i got error

```
at com.example.aquib.chatapp.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:64)
```

this is activities codes

```
     //MessagingService Activity
     String notification_click = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
    String notification_data = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_userId");
    Intent intent = new Intent(notification_click);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("user_id",notification_data);

    //getting it over here ProfileActivity
    final String User_Id = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id");
    currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProfileActivity.this);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(User_Id);
    databaseFriend =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends");
    databaseReq = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friend_Req");
    databaseNotification = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notification");

//updated
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference onData;
FirebaseAuth auth;
DatabaseReference databaseReq;
DatabaseReference databaseFriend;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
DatabaseReference databaseNotification;
DatabaseReference mRootref;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
FirebaseUser currentUser;
String mCurrentState;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    onData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

    final String User_Id = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id");

    mCurrentState = "not_friends";
    final Button Decbutton = findViewById(R.id.button5);
    final Button Reqbutton = findViewById(R.id.button4);
    final TextView user_name = findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    final TextView status_name = findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    final ImageView profile_image = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProfileActivity.this);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(User_Id);
        databaseFriend = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends");
        databaseReq = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friend_Req");
        databaseNotification = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notification");
        mRootref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        progressDialog.setTitle("Loading User Data");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while we load the data");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String user = dataSnapshot.child("user").getValue().toString();
                String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                user_name.setText(user);
                status_name.setText(status);

                Picasso.with(ProfileActivity.this).load(image).into(profile_image);

                // -------------------- Friend List / Request Feature--------------------

                databaseReq.child(currentUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(User_Id)) {

                            String req_type = dataSnapshot.child(User_Id).child("request_type").getValue().toString();

                            if (req_type.equals("received")) {

                                Reqbutton.setText("Accept Friend Request");
                                mCurrentState = "req_received";
                                Decbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            } else if (req_type.equals("sent")) {

                                mCurrentState = "req_sent";
                                Reqbutton.setText("Cancel Friend Request");
                                Decbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            }

                            progressDialog.dismiss();


                        } else {

                            databaseFriend.child(currentUser.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(User_Id)) {

                                        Reqbutton.setText("Unfriend this Person");
                                        mCurrentState = "friends";
                                        Decbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                    }

                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });

                        }

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        // -------------------- Friend Request--------------------

        Reqbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Reqbutton.setEnabled(false);

                // -------------------- Not Friend State --------------------

                if (mCurrentState.equals("not_friends")) {

                    DatabaseReference newNotifref = mRootref.child("Notification").child(User_Id).push();
                    String newNotifId = newNotifref.getKey();

                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("from", currentUser.getUid());
                    hashMap.put("type", "request");


                    Map requestMap = new HashMap();
                    requestMap.put("Friend_Req/" + currentUser.getUid() + "/" + User_Id + "/" + "request_type", "sent");
                    requestMap.put("Friend_Req/" + User_Id + "/" + currentUser.getUid() + "/" + "request_type", "received");
                    requestMap.put("Notification/" + User_Id + "/" + newNotifId, hashMap);

                    mRootref.updateChildren(requestMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                            if (databaseError == null) {

                                Reqbutton.setEnabled(true);
                                Reqbutton.setText("Cancel Friend Request");
                                Reqbutton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.colorBtn));
                                mCurrentState = "req_sent";
                                Decbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "There was some error in sending request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                            Reqbutton.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });
                }

                // -------------------- Cancel Friend Request--------------------

                if (mCurrentState.equals("req_sent")) {

                    Map map = new HashMap();
                    map.put("Friend_Req/" + currentUser.getUid() + "/" + User_Id, null);
                    map.put("Friend_Req/" + User_Id + "/" + currentUser.getUid(), null);

                    mRootref.updateChildren(map, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                            if (databaseError == null) {
                                Reqbutton.setEnabled(true);
                                Reqbutton.setText("Send Friend Request");
                                mCurrentState = "not_friends";
                                Decbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Error in doing it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });


                // -------------------- Req Received State --------------------

                if (mCurrentState.equals("req_received")) {

                    final String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

                    Map map = new HashMap();
                    map.put("Friends/" + currentUser.getUid() + "/" + User_Id + "/date", currentDate);
                    map.put("Friends/" + User_Id + "/" + currentUser.getUid() + "/date", currentDate);
                    map.put("Friend_Req/" + currentUser.getUid() + "/" + User_Id, null);
                    map.put("Friend_Req/" + User_Id + "/" + currentUser.getUid(), null);

                    mRootref.updateChildren(map, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                            if (databaseError == null) {

                                Reqbutton.setText("Unfriend this Person");
                                Reqbutton.setEnabled(true);
                                mCurrentState = "friends";
                                Decbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Error in Receiving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                        }
                    });

                //----------------- UnFriend ----------------------

                if (mCurrentState.equals("friends")) {

                    Map map = new HashMap();

                    map.put("Friends/" + currentUser.getUid() + "/" + User_Id, null);
                    map.put("Friends/" + User_Id + "/" + currentUser.getUid(), null);

                    mRootref.updateChildren(map, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                            if (databaseError == null) {

                                mCurrentState = "not_friends";
                                Reqbutton.setEnabled(true);
                                Reqbutton.setText("Send Friend Request");
                                Decbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                        }
                    });

                }

            }
        });

        Decbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Map map = new HashMap();
                map.put("Friend_Req/" + currentUser.getUid() + "/" + User_Id, null);
                map.put("Friend_Req/" + User_Id + "/" + currentUser.getUid(), null);

                mRootref.updateChildren(map, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                        if (databaseError == null) {

                            Decbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Reqbutton.setText("Send Friend Request");
                            mCurrentState = "not_friends";

                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Error in the dec btn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });

}
```

}

Comment: Please share the content of the line at which are you getting this error.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YjOVw8i1-7zYobxjP4b_p-u0xh_QAKE5  here  it is

Comment: Can you post it (Not a link to your drive) on Stack Over flow (edit your question).

Comment: yea sure.. Updated

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: **println needs a message**

You probably need to set a message to `println` like following code:

```
System.out.println("Your message");
```

But, that's not the point here. That's pure java which we use `println` for. **You better to use** logging on android development. (You can also use both)

[**Write log messages in your code**](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/#systemLogWrite)

Comment: if i add whole code in try block the Reqactivity is opening but the content/Views in the activity they are not changing(setText and profilePic).

Comment: Look, you better to check if my solution solves the first and this question or not. Then we could maybe check another issues. Also, what do you mean by whole code? would you tell me or show me what did you did so far? i don't get which codes you meant, thanks. Also, if views didn't changed, try with runonUi method this can help.